# Fetch user data from google analytics with python using userActivity.search

Tags: python, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to fetch user data from google analytics using the following google python api:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

In the example shown, there is the function 'get_report' looks like this:

```
def get_report(analytics):
  """Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.

  Args:
    analytics: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  Returns:
    The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```

This syntax works well but in order to get user data I think I have to stick to the following manual:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search

To make it even clearer I wanted to run the example from here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/user-reporting

The example looks like this:

```
{
    "viewId": "9999999",
    "user": {
        "type": "CLIENT_ID",
        "userId": "1034600000.76425000000"
    },
    "dateRange": {
        "startDate": "2018-01-01",
        "endDate": "2018-12-31",
    }
}
```

But this example does not state how to define the function "get_report" from above. 
From what I understand the argument 'analysis' used in 'get_reports' has a method or class called 'userActivity' which it has. But according to the the second link from above it should also have a method called 'search' which it doesn't have! So how do I get/access the method 'search'? Does it have to be initialized when initiliazing the class 'userActivity'?

At the moment my syntax looks like this:

```
def get_report(analytics):
  """Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.

  Args:
    analytics: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  Returns:
    The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  return analytics.userActivity().search(
      {
    "viewId": VIEW_ID,
    "user": {
        "type": "CLIENT_ID",
        "userId": "310383817.1547668323"
    },
    "dateRange": {
        "startDate": "2019-01-30",
        "endDate": "2019-02-01",
    }
}
  ).execute()
```

But this syntax does ***not*** work! The error message says:

method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer ...
You just have to put the arguments of the search method into a variable called `body`. It should look like this:

```py
def get_report(analytics):
    """Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.

    Args:
        analytics: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
    Returns:
        The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
    """
    return analytics.userActivity().search(
        body = {
            "viewId": VIEW_ID,
            "user": {
                "type": "CLIENT_ID",
                "userId": "310383817.1547668323"
            },
            "dateRange": {
                "startDate": "2019-01-30",
                "endDate": "2019-02-01",
            }
        }
    ).execute()
```

Comment: I have a similar, but different problem.. I need to run this through a for loop to get all the data for various users for various sites (So something like ```for site in VIEW_id_list: for user in user_id_list: append a dictonary or a list``` to get all the data for all the users of all the sites into a table.... I am dumbstruck by the difficulty of google analytics.. Where can I get a list of all the users?

Comment: Where do you get userid to pass into the request body?

Comment: @0004: I gut the client id from google analytics itself. I can parse the whole data in google analytics and have a look at all users including their user ids. There, I got a client id.Using this API here I just wanted to fetch the data and to use it in Python.

Comment: @the_economist so what did you replace `"userId": "310383817.1547668323"`  with? Was it a value you pulled from your Google Analytics API if so where ?

Comment: @the_economist the documentation to capture the client_id sends me to analytics.js documenation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#clientId 


despite the fact it was linked to the python docs where I was working out of

Comment: @0004: No, I didn't pull it from the Google Analytics API. I never tried to pull a userID with the API. I got it as I logged in to Google Analytics via the browser.

Comment: @0004: There is a difference between a userID and the clientID. The userID stems from a user / customer using our company's shop. The clientID is an ID from your Google Account as far as I know.